# What kind of voice recording machine was that in The Innkeepers?

Tags: the-innkeepers

In [The Innkeepers (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1594562/), what kind of voice recording machine was that which Claire and Luke use? In what fields is that machine used in real life?

[image: machine1]
[image: machine2]

Comment: Is it ever expressed what the recording device is used for?  How is knowing what the device is important to the film?  As it stands this seems like a trivia question.

Comment: In the film, they use it for hopefully recording the sounds of the ghost. I wonder if this device is realistic and used or not in real life (for other purposes).

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia lists this type of microphone as a [shotgun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone).

> Shotgun microphones are the most highly directional. They have small lobes of sensitivity to the left, right, and rear but are significantly less sensitive to the side and rear than other directional microphones. This results from placing the element at the back end of a tube with slots cut along the side; wave cancellation eliminates much of the off-axis sound. Due to the narrowness of their sensitivity area, shotgun microphones are commonly used on television and film sets, in stadiums, and for field recording of wildlife.

If the characters are trying to pick up sounds of paranormal activity, the noise cancellation they speak of would be beneficial. I couldn't find this specific model, but looking in google for "Shotgun Condenser Microphone", brought page after page - there are dozens of models.

This one looks [closest so far](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Audix-UEM-81S-Battery-Powered-Shotgun-Condenser-Microphone-103375853-i1176481.gc).